# Providing tasks in different paths

Tags: c#, async-await

Currently, I am wondering a little bit.

```
        public async Task MoveMyStuff( CancellationToken cancellationToken )
        {
            if( IsMyConditionGiven() ) 
                await this.myService.ExecuteAsync( MyMoveCommand(), cancellationToken );
        }
```

Ta-da:

> ========== Build: 4 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

The invocation of `MoveMyStuff` awaits this task.
So the question is what will happen concerning task processing when the condition `IsMyConditionGiven` is false?

Well, perhaps that is an answer:

> That is, a call to the method returns a Task, but when the Task is
>   completed, any await expression that's awaiting the Task evaluates to
>   void.

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx)

Comment: If `IsMyConditionGiven` returns `false` the task returned from `MoveMyStuff` will complete synchronously.

Comment: @Lee: You are perfectly correct; please add this as an answer!